# Android: Obtaining Contact List via CursorLoader - Name/Number/NumberType

Tags: android

I'm loading the Phone's contact list for use with an AutoCompleteTextView and I want to show the Phone Type (Work, Home, etc) via test but right now I just get the numerical type ID back (1,2,3)

How can I get the name:  Here's the code below - all help appreciated.

```
static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[]
        {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE
};

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
{
    try
    {
        String SELECTION = "((" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' )" + "AND (" + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1))";
        //        + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " like 'p%' )" + "AND ("+ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER +"=1))";

        if (mSelection.length() > 0) {
            SELECTION = "((" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                    + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " like '" + mSelection + "%' )" + "AND (" + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1))";
        }

        return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, SELECTION, null,
                " DISPLAY_NAME ASC");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateLoader:Exception:" + R.string.Exception + ":" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

//this is how the cursor adapter is set:

```
            mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contactview, null,
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE},
                    new int[]{R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontNo, R.id.ccontType}, 0);
            mTxtPhoneNo.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: It sounds like you might be getting the id # (if that's the correct name). have you tried appending `.getString(), getLong()` etc.  With cursors, which I've used you do something along the lines of `csr(<index>>).getString();` where index is a numeric offset starting with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Phone.getTypeLabel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html#getTypeLabel(android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) to get the correct (localized) label for the phone. In this case your query should also select the `Phone.LABEL` column, and the value of this column should be passed as the third argument to the aforementioned method (in the event that type found in the cursor row is `TYPE_CUSTOM`, the `LABEL`column contains the actual label).

```
static final String[] PROJECTION = {Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, 
        Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL};
...
int type = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
String label = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.LABEL));
CharSequence resolvedLabel = Phone.getTypeLabel(mResources, type, label);
```

**EDIT**

First, your updated code still does not include `Phone.LABEL` in the projection. Perhaps this was an oversight in your edit, but in any case, you need to select that column.

Second, `SimpleCursorAdapter` simply dumps the value of a column into a corresponding view. As I demonstrated above, this is not sufficient to display a proper label, you need additional logic beyond that provided by `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

You can write your own class extending `CursorAdapter` and include that logic in `bindView()`, or you can use [`SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setViewBinder(android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder)) and provide an implementation like the following:

```
mAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean onBindView(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.ccontType) {
            // this view needs the label
            int type = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
            String label = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.LABEL));
            CharSequence resolvedLabel = Phone.getTypeLabel(view.getResources(), type, label);
            ((TextView) view).setText(resolvedLabel);

            return true; // we've handled the binding for the view
        }

        return false; // allow adapter to use it's own basic logic
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry I still cant get it to work - I've pulled the Type in name form when I was using the old cursor but how do I edit a cursorloader to set the proper label.  I updated the code above with my simple cursor adapter ...